# Compare folder file names against an array

Tags: vbscript

This is my first post and I am a novice at scripting. Instead of beating my head against the wall until I finally figure it out I decided to sign up here and ask for some help since I often use this site when looking for answers.

I am trying to write a vbscript that compares all the file names in a given folder against an array which contains "approved" filenames for that folder. If the file name in the folder doesn't match any of the names in the array, then it should delete the file in the folder. My script seems to compare just fine but when it finds a file that does not match it seems to want to delete the last filename it checked and not the file name that doesn't match. Here is the what I have. Your input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

There are 12 "acceptable" file names. 4 file names with 3 different extensions each.

```
    DIM objFSO, objUser, userName, strFolder, objFolder, objFiles, sigTxt1, sigTxt2, sigTxt3, 
    sigCust, sigExt1, sigExt2, sigExt3

    SET objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    SET objUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    userName = objUser.UserName
    strFolder = "C:\Users\" & userName & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    SET objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
    SET objFiles = objFolder.files
    sigTxt1 = "FSignature"
    sigTxt2 = "PSignature"
    sigTxt3 = "PWSignature"
    sigExt1 = ".htm"
    sigExt2 = ".rtf"
    sigExt3 = ".txt"
    sigCust = "CustomSignature"
    DIM SigName
    SigName=Array(sigTxt1 & sigExt1, sigTxt1 & sigExt2,  sigTxt1 & sigExt3, sigTxt2 & sigExt1, sigTxt2 &
    sigExt2, sigTxt2 & sigExt3, sigTxt3 & sigExt1, sigTxt3 & sigExt2, sigTxt3 & sigExt3, 
    sigCust & sigExt1, sigCust & sigExt2, sigCust & sigExt3)

    DIM i, sigFoldFile, sigArrName, sName1, sName2, noMatch
    i = 1
    noMatch = "True"
    DO WHILE i  0 THEN
            noMatch = "True"
            wscript.echo "Match = NO" & vbNewline & sname1 & "  " & sName2 & vbNewline & "noMatch = " & 
    noMatch
        ELSE
            noMatch = "False"
            wscript.echo "Match = YES" & vbNewline & sname1 & " = " & sName2 & vbNewline & "noMatch = " & 
    noMatch
            EXIT FOR
        NEXT
    If noMatch = "True" THEN
        wscript.echo "Deleteing file " & sName2
    '   objFSO.DeleteFile sName2
    END IF
    i = i + 1
    wscript.echo i               'temporary line for checking that value of i
    NEXT
    LOOP
```

*Update*
I have this working now. Thank you everyone. I'll post the script in case it can help others. I realized that my objFSO.DeleteFile line needed to include strFolder so that the full path was specified. I also added a file count variable because the "<" number in the "DO WHILE i < 13" statement cannot be a static number. This is due to the possibility that the number of files in a user's folder could be more or less.

```
    Option Explicit
    DIM objFSO, objUser, userName, strFolder, objFolder, objFiles, sigTxt1, 
    sigTxt2, sigCust, sigExt1, sigExt2, sigExt3
    SET objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    SET objUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    userName = objUser.UserName
    strFolder = "C:\Users\" & userName & 
    "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    SET objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
    SET objFiles = objFolder.files
    sigTxt1 = "FSignature"
    sigTxt2 = "PSignature"
    sigCust = "CustomSignature"
    sigExt1 = ".htm"
    sigExt2 = ".rtf"
    sigExt3 = ".txt"
    DIM SigName
    SigName=Array(sigTxt1 & sigExt1, sigTxt1 & sigExt2,  sigTxt1 & sigExt3, 
    sigTxt2 & sigExt1, sigTxt2 & sigExt2, sigTxt2 & sigExt3, sigCust & 
    sigExt1, sigCust & sigExt2, sigCust & sigExt3)
    '------------------------------------------LINE 19
    DIM f, i, j, sigFoldFile, sigArrName, sName1, sName2, noMatch
    f = objFolder.Files.count
    i = 1
    j = f + 1
    DO WHILE i < j
    FOR EACH sigFoldFile in objFiles
        noMatch = "True"
        sName2 = sigFoldFile.Name
        FOR EACH sigArrName in SigName
            sName1 = sigArrName
        IF sName2 <> sName1 THEN
            noMatch = "True"
        ELSE
            noMatch = "False"
            EXIT FOR
        END IF
        NEXT
    IF noMatch = "True" THEN
        wscript.echo "Deleteing file " & sName2
        sigFoldFile.Attributes = 0
        objFSO.DeleteFile strFolder & sName2
    END IF
    i = i + 1
    NEXT
    LOOP
```

Comment: Shouldn't you set noMatch = "True" immediately after For Each sigFoldFile in objFiles?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead of array? This will allow you to straight away fetch the match without having to loop every time.

Comment: Honeyboy Wilson, Thank you for your suggestion. I had thought of that, but my rational was that I only needed to set noMatch=True the first time. Although this does seem to work fine, after consideration of your suggestion I did move the line since it is better practice.

Comment: Pankaj, Thanks for your reply. I haven't used a dictionary before but I have seen scripts where people use it. I will have to look into learning this technique.

Comment: Well, my suggestion wasn't regarding a "better practice". My suggestion was an attempt to solve your problem. I guess it didn't?

Comment: Honeyboy Wilson, I think  it did. Thank you.